# Wordpress - Pagination post, order by: meta_key only from current category

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I trying to make a pagination links from my website.

---

### **Schema:**

---

```
Serie | (category)
    |_ Temporada 1 (taxonomy: temporada)
            |_ Episodio 1 (posts 1 - meta_key: numeroepisodio)
            |_ Episodio 2 (posts 2 - meta_key: numeroepisodio)
            |_ Episodio 3 (posts 3 - meta_key: numeroepisodio)
            |_ Episodio 4 (posts 4 - meta_key: numeroepisodio)
            |_ ...
    |_ Temporada 2  (taxonomy: temporada)
            |_ Episodio 1 (posts 1 - meta_key: numeroepisodio)
            |_ Episodio 2 (posts 2 - meta_key: numeroepisodio)
            |_ Episodio 3 (posts 3 - meta_key: numeroepisodio)
            |_ Episodio 4 (posts 4 - meta_key: numeroepisodio)
            |_ ...

Another Serie 1
    |_ ...
Another Serie 2
    |_ ...
```

---

### **Problem:**

---

When I create my posts, the pagination are order by DATE.
Can help me to make this order by meta_key, in same taxonomy only for current category?

---

### **Code:**

---

```
<?php
    $prev_post = get_adjacent_post( true, '', true );
    $next_post = get_adjacent_post( true, '', false );

    if ( !is_a( $next_post , 'WP_Post' ) ) {
        $query_args = array (
        'post_type'         => 'post',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'meta_key'          => 'numeroepisodio',
        'orderby'           => 'meta_value meta_value_num',
        'order'             => 'DESC',
        'paged'             => $paged,
        'tax_query'         => array( 
                                array( 'taxonomy' => 'categry'),
                                array( 'taxonomy' => 'temporada') 
                        )
    );
        $oldest = get_posts($query_args);
        $next_post = $oldest[0];
    }
    if ( !is_a( $prev_post , 'WP_Post' ) ) {
        $latest = get_posts($query_args);
        $prev_post = $latest[0];
    }
?>
<?php if ( is_a( $prev_post , 'WP_Post' ) ) : ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $prev_post->ID ); ?>"><div id="temporadas-dropdown"><i class="fa fa-caret-left"></i> ANTERIOR</div></a>
<?php endif; ?> 

<?php if ( is_a( $next_post , 'WP_Post' ) ) : ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $next_post->ID ); ?>"><div id="temporadas-dropdown">SIGUIENTE <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></div></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here is a live example: http://series.enlatino.net/ver-online/silicon-valley/

Thanks so much in advice!

Comment: it says categry in your code for tax_query

Comment: Fixed, but that no change anythings. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I found this:

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: (#73190) Alter adjacent post link sort order */
function wpse73190_adjacent_post_sort( $orderby )
{
    return "ORDER BY p.menu_order DESC LIMIT 1";
}
add_filter( 'get_previous_post_sort', 'wpse73190_adjacent_post_sort' );
add_filter( 'get_next_post_sort', 'wpse73190_adjacent_post_sort' );
```

from [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73190/can-the-next-prev-post-links-be-ordered-by-menu-order-or-by-a-meta-key) - which will explain it better, so check it out... the accepted answer, but essentially you might be able to alter the query with that filter, and there's different filters - where, join, sort for both previous and next.

---

### Totally different answer:

I am not really a fan of doing it manually but this might work - I did not test it though and my full understanding of taxonomies and the wordpress DB is somewhat lacking.

```
function get_adjacent_episode($post, $prev_or_next) {
    global $wpdb;
    
    $prev_or_next = ($prev_or_next === 'previous') ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
    $operator = ($prev_or_next === 'previous') ? '<' : '>';
    
    $cur_episode = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'numeroepisodio', true);
    
    $query = sprintf("select p.ID from $wpdb->posts p 
        inner join $wpdb->postmeta m 
        on p.ID = m.post_id
        inner join $wpdb->terms_relationships r
        on p.ID = r.object_id
        where r.term_taxonomy_id = (select term_taxonomy_id from $wpdb->term_taxonomy where taxonomy = '%s' limit 1) 
        and p.post_type = 'post' and m.meta_key = '%s' and m.meta_value %s %s
        order by m.meta_key %s limit 1", 'temporada', 'numeroepisodio', $operator, $cur_episode, $prev_or_next);
        
    $adjacent_post = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    return $adjacent_post;
}
```

Call it:

`$next_post = get_adjacent_episode($post, 'next');`

`$prev_post = get_adjacent_episode($post, 'previous');`

Note that the query has only `select p.ID`, so you'd only be able to access `$next_post->ID` but you could expand this select to capture more of the result if needed.

Comment: Hi @amurrell, and thanks for your reply. My question to your answers is.. thats a good practices? Is secure to query directly to the database?

Comment: I encourage you to read about the [wpdb object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) and specifically the idea of using [prepare](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) to avoid sql injection, which I've already done using sprintf(). Personally I think that another solution manipulating the sort filters would be kind of a hack job and much less efficient... common practice? Idk, it's a more manual approach and maybe that makes it more advanced - not sure.